# Case statement duplicating rows - teradata

Tags: case, teradata

i have the following query and the problem is in the Case statement. It s being used in a Join condition. for some reason is bringing up both alternatives from the case

here s the code

```
SELECT C.GREGORIAN_MONTH_ID
,C.BUSINESS_PARTY_ID
,C.TOTAL_MONTO
,C.Capitas_Puntuales
,C.CUIT
,nb_apellido
,nb_oficial_actual
,nb_cne_obe
,nb_nodo
,nb_territorio
,cd_area_negocio

FROM (SELECT gregorian_month_id
                ,business_party_id
                ,Case when BUSINESS_PARTY_ID in (88888,200) then '9999999999999' else business_party_ident_num end CUIT
                ,SUM(amt_accum) Total_Monto
                ,count(*) Capitas_Puntuales

                FROM  dbsreg.A127932_PARTY_MAIN_PAYROLL_HISTORY
                where gregorian_month_id= 201806
                group by 1,2,3
                ) C 

LEFT JOIN 
    (select NU_CUIT, nb_apellido,nb_oficial_actual, nb_cne_obe, nb_nodo, nb_territorio,cd_area_negocio
    ,(fh_corte/100 + 190000) gregorian_month_id
    from dbsreg.a119527_base_info_gerencial 
    ) G

on C.CUIT = G.NU_CUIT 
and  (case 
         when C.gregorian_month_id  in (G.gregorian_month_id) then C.gregorian_month_id 
         else C.gregorian_month_id -1
        END) = G.gregorian_month_id  
ORDER BY C.BUSINESS_PARTY_ID
```

anyone can tell what s going on there?

Comment: Can you provide an actual/expected output sample?

Comment: What do actually want to return? Of course your CASE joins on both `C.gregorian_month_id -1` and `C.gregorian_month_id` as you compare to all rows with the same `CUIT`

Answer (score 0):

You final query returns C.BUSINESS_PARTY_ID which is not transformed by Case.  Your case statement also draws on BUSINESS_PARTY_ID.  Did you mean to have C.CUIT instead of C.BUSINESS_PARTY_ID in your outer select statement?

Comment: what i m trying to join is an identification number (c.CUIT) and a time period (gregorian_month_id). The info in the first table C has data from 201807 but the second table C goes until 201806. what i want to achieve from the join is to bring the info from table G from the time period that matches C but if it doesn t match then just bring the time period -1 (201805) from G

Comment: So you want to select the most recent matching record from G?

Answer (score 0):

long story short, i moved the case withing to a  where statement from table C and added a userdefined value for the gregorian:

```
SELECT C.GREGORIAN_MONTH_ID
,C.BUSINESS_PARTY_ID
,C.TOTAL_MONTO
,C.Capitas_Puntuales
,C.CUIT
,nb_apellido
,nb_oficial_actual
,nb_cne_obe
,nb_nodo
,nb_territorio
,cd_area_negocio

FROM (SELECT gregorian_month_id
                ,business_party_id
                ,Case when BUSINESS_PARTY_ID in (88888,200) then '9999999999999' else business_party_ident_num end CUIT
                ,SUM(amt_accum) Total_Monto
                ,count(*) Capitas_Puntuales

                FROM  dbsreg.A127932_PARTY_MAIN_PAYROLL_HISTORY
                where gregorian_month_id= ?FECHA_BASE
                group by 1,2,3
                ) C 

LEFT JOIN 
    (select NU_CUIT, nb_apellido,nb_oficial_actual, nb_cne_obe, nb_nodo, nb_territorio,cd_area_negocio
    ,(fh_corte/100 + 190000) gregorian_month_id
    from dbsreg.a119527_base_info_gerencial 
    where gregorian_month_id = (Case when ?FECHA_BASE = (gregorian_month_id) then gregorian_month_id else gregorian_month_id-1 end ) 
    ) G

on C.CUIT = G.NU_CUIT 
ORDER BY C.BUSINESS_PARTY_ID
```